# Field-level authorization with Amplify GrraphQL

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm having trouble sorting out [field-level authorization](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#field-level-authorization). I would like to have a particular field in a model be read-only.

Here's a simplified version of the schema:

```
type Thing
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      {
        allow: groups
        groups: ["Admins"]
        operations: [read, create, update]
      }
      { allow: private, operations: [read]}
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  foo: String
  bar: String
  baz: ID
    @auth(
      rules: [
        { allow: groups, groups: ["Admins"], operations: [read] }
      ]
    )
}
```

My expectation is that all users would be able to read `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`, but only members of `Admins` would be able to update `foo` and `bar`, but that not even Admins would be allowed to update `baz`. I'm finding, however, that Admins are still able to write to `baz`, which I do not want.

I would think that field-level rules would have precedence over model-level rules.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to be possible, [from the docs:](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/authorization-rules/#field-level-authorization-rules)

> When an authorization rule is added to a field, it'll strictly define the authorization rules applied on the field. **Field-level authorization rules do not inherit model-level authorization rules**. Meaning, only the specified field-level authorization rule is applied.

It seems like if you add a field-level rule the model ignores whatever authorizations you have at the model-level.  There are several examples here for good reference: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/auth/#field-level-authorization

As far as the issue you are seeing, not sure, seems like you've set it up correctly, maybe there's another issue here?